Why does Java to invoke Integer.intValue() whenever the ternary operator ends up in the else case?
When I supply seed as anything greater than 4000, it does return it as is. But for any seed less than or equal to 4000 (i.e. when the ternary operator condition evaluates to false) this program ends up with a null pointer exception.
However, it works correctly if seed is declared as Integer in getRankFromMain params.
public class TestSomething {
    private static Integer getRank() {
        return null;
    }

    private static Integer getRankFromMain(int seed) {
        return seed > 4000 ? seed : getRank();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer rank = getRankFromMain(1000);
        System.out.println(rank);
    }
}


Provide the full stack trace and the exception.

The return-type of the ternary operator must be equal in both cases. Since the "good" case (seed) returns an int, the right side is autounboxed (docs.oracle.com) to an int (which is the cause of the NullPointerException). If we change the "good" case to Integer.valueOf(seed), the program works as expected. ideone.com demo

Of what use is it to return a null from getRank()?

No reason to return an Integer at all here. Be efficient: return int.

@WJS That's what's called a [mre].
